# How to send CV not to apply for a job, but just to keep options open?

Tags: professionalism, career-development, promotion

A buddy from my fitness group is a top exec at a huge, world-famous company, and a few days ago he said they might need someone with my profile - junior/middle management level - and to send my most recent CV so he can arrange an informal meeting with the other directors (WOW!).

The problem is: I truly love my job and had a great progression (promoted right after probation), have created strong bonds with my senior management and everyone in the company trusts me. It happens quite rarely nowadays, so I am quite attached and aim at staying loyal to my company.

However, I am curious about meeting these people from the top company, maybe to keep options open for the future, maybe in 4 or 5 years or so, or only to know other people in my industry.

My only fear is that if my CV is passed around and ends up in the wrong hands (someone who knows my current employer), I could be perceived as un-loyal and that could ruin my future at my current company... and I have told my boss many times, also in my yearly review, that I would like to stay at my company as long as possible.

What would you advise in my situation? Would sending the CV be a career suicide?

Comment: In some countries this practice you describe is considered anti-ethical and can lead you to never being offered a job by that company ever again. You also close the doors to other companies if they learn about that. Instead of sending a CV, do some real networking. Meet people. Show to the market that you're good.

Answer (score 4):

> What would you advise in my situation? Would sending the CV be a
>   career suicide?

Since you have no immediate interest in jumping to a new company, in my opinion it doesn't make sense to send your CV.

While it's unlikely to be career suicide, you have correctly pointed out that there are a few potential pitfalls, with regard to word getting back to your current company.

But in addition to that, how do you expect your CEO buddy and his Directors to react when you have taken up their time, but then say "I would like to stay at my company as long as possible"? I know that I would feel I was lied to, or at a minimum that I was being played.

I think it would be far better if you were up front with your buddy the CEO. Instead of sending your CV, why don't you just say "I'm really not at a point in my life where I would consider moving to a new company, and I have no intention of leaving anytime in the near future. But I'd still love to have a chat with your Directors, if you think it would be appropriate, as your company does sound very interesting."

That way, you might still get a chance to talk with them, but they won't feel odd when you just end things at that point.

I've done this sort of thing in the past. For me it helped grow my network of connections.

Comment: You could even try to turn this into a new business opportunity. I once had an interview planned at a company, but turned it into a networking talk after I got hired by another company. Of course, this only works when there could potentially be cooperation between your current employer and the company of your friend. I would make this explicit to your current employer and the company of your friend. Approaching the meeting like this makes your current employer happy (potentially new business) and let's you meet new people.